# How to stop Windows 10 Home from automatic restarts

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

I did run my overnight computations and when I came to my computer, it is restarted :-( [I am not sure why](https://superuser.com/q/1096075/93604), but it is quite possible that it could have been automatic restart due to updates.

How do I stop Windows 10 from automatic restarts?

I have found [this setting](http://lifehacker.com/prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-restarting-your-p-1723647582):

[image]

and I did apply it now, but **is it enough to block all automatic restarts, even when I am not present at the computer and cannot react to the notification?** In the past I noticed that some similar notifications had a countdown timer and if you didn't react, it restarted the computer (quite stupid, but that's how it SW nowadays...).

Comment: Do you have `Windows 10 Home` or `Windows 10 Professional` installed?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Not a duplicate - this question is older. It was here before the duplicate even existed.

Comment: Age isn't a relevant factor in this case.  The other thread has more and better answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is enough to stop the computer from automatically restarting, after installing updates you will be prompted to manually schedule a restart.

Comment: so aren't there any countdown timers in the notification prompt?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Comment: If you set Windows to notify you available updates, it works exactly like previous versions of Windows, Windows 10 simply requires you to install them when prompted.  Windows 10 Home also requires you to run the current build, and does not let you defer that upgrade, that option is limited to `Windows 10 Professional`,

Comment: @Ramhound I am confused now. Could you please post a full answer to my question and whether or not this setting is sufficient and won't reboot automatically?

Comment: @Tomas - I am not going to duplicate an existing answer.

Comment: @Ramhound you woudln't duplicate this answer. This answer is incomplete for me, as it didn't answer the last paragraph of my question clearly. I have asked Kodikuu to complete it and he didn't respond. Only you responded (thanks) and your comment is not clear to me regarding the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: @Tomas setting notify to schedule a restart is not all you need to do. you can keep deferring updates to a future time, but eventually you won't be able to anymore and windows _will_ force a restart, especially if it's a security update.